# How to increment Datagridview.row value?

Tags: vb.net, foreach, datagridview, increment

I have code to insert values into a Datagridview with 2 columns.
But with the `For Each` value I have only the first value and not all the values.

I think it's because I can add the other because the code take only the first value and don't add the others in the rows.

```
DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2
DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Products"
DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Links"
Dim page = New HtmlDocument()
page.Load("C:\Users\test\Desktop\thanos.txt")
Dim lists = page.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='marketplace-collectible-list']")
For Each list In lists
    Dim prod As String = list.SelectSingleNode(".//*[@class = 'catalog-item-name']").InnerText.Trim()
    Dim link As String = list.SelectSingleNode(".//*[@class = 'image-container']//img//@src").Attributes("src").Value
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(prod, link)
Next
```

How to increment the others value ?
Edit :
I tried the following without success.

```
For Each list In lists
    Dim f As Integer
    f = DataGridView1.Rows.Count
    Dim n As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Item(n).Cells(0).Value = list.SelectSingleNode(".//*[@class = 'catalog-item-name']").InnerText.Trim() + 1
    DataGridView1.Rows.Item(n).Cells(1).Value = list.SelectSingleNode(".//*[@class = 'image-container']//img//@src").Attributes("src").Value + 1
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(f)
Next
```

With this code i have all the correct data in only one column:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Products"
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Links"


        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        Dim link As String = "https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/hobbydb/catalog_items?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=thanos+sideshow&commit=Go"
        Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load(link)
        Dim div As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='marketplace-collectible-list']")
        For Each node As HtmlNode In div.SelectNodes("//div[@class='marketplace-collectible-list']//a[@class = 'catalog-item-name']")
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(node.InnerText.Trim())
        Next
        For Each node2 As HtmlNode In div.SelectNodes("//div[@class='image-container']//img//@src")
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(node2.Attributes("src").Value)
        Next
End Sub
End Class
```

But i want node & node2 in differents columns.

I try this too, but i have only the first value :

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Products"
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Links"
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        Dim link As String = "https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/hobbydb/catalog_items?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=thanos+sideshow&commit=Go"
        Dim page = New HtmlWeb().Load(link)
        Dim lists = page.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='marketplace-collectible-list']")
        For Each list In lists
            For i As Integer = 0 To lists.Count - 1
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = lists(i).SelectSingleNode(".//*[@class = 'catalog-item-name']").InnerText.Trim()
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = lists(i).SelectSingleNode(".//*[@class = 'image-container']//img//@src").Attributes("src").Value
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: No idea what you're talking about.  Please try to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.  Too many words is better than not enough.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Are the rows added at all or are their values blank?

Comment: i try to catch all the values. But i have only the first value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        'create the datatable as a data source for the datagridview
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Product"))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Link"))

    'connect to the site
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
    Dim siteaddress As String = "https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/hobbydb/catalog_items?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=thanos+sideshow&commit=Go"
    Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load(siteaddress)
    Dim div As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='marketplace-collectible-list']")
    'get data
    For Each item As HtmlNode In div.SelectNodes("*//div[@class = 'row catalog-item-info']")
        Dim product As HtmlNode = item.SelectSingleNode("*//a[@class = 'catalog-item-name']")
        Dim link As HtmlNode = item.SelectSingleNode("*//div[@class = 'image-container']//img//@src")
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {product.InnerText.Trim(), link.Attributes("src").Value})
    Next

    'bind data
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Too bad i cannot try what you are trying but if i look at it, you have lists as a collection and a datagridview which is still empty, and you want to fill it while changing lists collection index at the same time...

I think this should work for you, if you have declared lists type you would have helped me more helping you, you should make sure lists is a (list of something) don't just `dim lists` like that, Please try:

```
for i as integer = 0 to lists.count - 1
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = lists(i).SelectSingleNode(".//*[@class = 'catalog-item-name']").InnerText.Trim() + 1
    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = lists(i).SelectSingleNode(".//*[@class = 'image-container']//img//@src").Attributes("src").Value
next
```

Comment: I try but i have the same result. I edited the code with the url because nobody have the txt file. I try to get the values in diferrents columns.